# mvn package error: unknown host repo.maven.apache.org

Tags: maven-3

I'm using intelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 and when

```
mvn package
```

is entered I get this message

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Building test1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.344s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 12 15:00:57 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/88M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I've set the proxy in ~/.m2/setting.xml
but, still get this error.
Helps please..

Comment: How does your `~/.m2/setting.xml` look now? If you remove this settings file, does it work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below command from the path where your pom.xml is present,

```
$ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:/
```

it worked for me.